Another approach to a graph problem
I'm attempting this problem:
Assuming that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with non-negative entries and $A^2 = 0$. What's the maximal number of positive entries in $A$?
The answer uses a graph theory approach. However, I'm not so familiar with graph theory. I have two questions

Is there a way to do this without using graph theory?
The answer implies when $n = 6$, there should be $3^2 = 9$ positive entries. I'm struggling to find an example for an $6 \times 6$ matrix with $9$ positive entries that would satisfy $A^2 = 0$ with all entries being non-negative. I can only find a matrix with $8$ positive entries. Can you give me an example of $A$ when $n = 6$?


The first question has been answered, also without using graph theory in this duplicate:
Let $A$ be a binary $n \times n$ matrix, such that $A^2=0$. What is the max num of $1$'s that $A$ could have?
The answer is given by the function $f(n)=\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$. For $n=2k$ this $k^2$, and for $n=2k+1$ this is $k^2+k$.
So let me answer the second question.
Here is an example of a binary matrix $A$ with nine entries equal to $1$ and all others equal to zero with $A^2=0$:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Can you answer my first question? I will then select yours. Thanks!

@user1691278 This site has several answers, not all using graph theory. You should have a look for the different proofs. It is also a matter of taste.
